# How to create dark mode button in google blogger theme

Tags: blogger

I'm trying to develop a Google blogger theme but I get a problem. darkmode button does not work in my blogger theme. i want to help me anybody how to create dark mode button in blogger theme. how to acces dark mode button in any blog posts and any pages
here is blog link https://tool-templateuser.blogspot.com/

dark mode button blog  please help me